# Laravel: unforeseen problems from echoing HTML in controller vs. passing data to view?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am storing full HTML content for specific pages in a DB and retrieving with Eloquent in my controllers. Is there any intricacy about Laravel 4 which requires

```
return View::make('mypage', compact('html'));
```

instead of

```
public function getMyPage()
{
 $html = HtmlTable::find(1);
 echo $html->html; 
}
```

I'm wondering what problems I might run into besides not following MVC best practice patterns if I bypass the view component in Laravel for certain static routes?

Comment: you won't get headers set correctly, some caching will be wrong (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag), etc.

Comment: +1 to what Udan said - Laravel handles alot of stuff in the request cycle - you should always return the view and let Laravel handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may bypass the `view` but not using `echo` instead use `return`:

```
return $html->html;
```

`Laravel` will `echo` it (The `Response` class handles the response where so many things happens behind the scene such as, setting `cookies`, `response headers` etc) but this is not a very good idea that you are doing now, `IMO`.

Comment: This was more for my curiosity, I generally don't advocate this approach either. Thanks!